# ToString rounding change in core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, floating-point, rounding, .net-4.8

The output of the code below changed from ["2.0" in .NET 4.7.2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uLKj7f) to "[1.9" in Core 3.1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yp1anh)

```
Console.WriteLine((1.95).ToString("N1"));
```

I think this may be related to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/ but I dont understand which of the floating point formatting changes is causing this difference.  What change in .net core 3.1 caused this?
Thanks.

Comment: can't answer the question but I find it interesting that if you set a variable of type double (or float) to 1.95f and do the same with it you get 2.0 which is the value I would expect to get for N1.  This (1.95f).ToString("N1") will also give you 2.0 - note the f after 1.95.  It is something in how it is interpreting the constant I believe and not necessarily the formatting.

Comment: I was using .Net 6 but it duplicates what you see in Core 3.1 - value of 1.9

Comment: @ScottMildenberger that's just causesed by differences in what numbers you can represent with a float or double. https://dotnetfiddle.net/jsFbNu